# Install offline C# dependencies for visual studio code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, omnisharp

I'm starting with .net core and visual studio code. After create a .net core web app (`dotnet new web`) I installed the C# extension by OmniSharp in order to enable intellisense and debbuging. Then when I restart VSCode a download is started to update C# dependencies. All works ok in my work because I have internet connection, but this is not the case in my home. I have downloaded the C# extension offline but when I restart VSCode try to update the dependencies, here is when it fails. Is there any way to package the dependencies so I can perform an offline installation in my home?

Comment: There is a local cache used if the network connectivity is off: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache ... IMO there is no way (currently) to extend the cache without manual labor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able of build an offline installation of C# extension for Visual Studio Code following [these](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/955#issuecomment-260981977) steps.